# Actionscript 3 | find minium Number inside different movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, numbers

I'm trying to make a user interface for dart players where up to 8 players are able to put their entries into a table. I want to highlight the actual leader with a "blinking movieclip" or something like that. Every Player has his own movieclip, imply a dynamic text field, which calculates the result.

My way is only working when exactly 4 players start the game.

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, showLeader);

function showLeader(evt: KeyboardEvent): void {

var a: Number = Number(player_1_content_mc.GESAMTPUNKTZAHL_TEXT.text);
var b: Number = Number(player_2_content_mc.GESAMTPUNKTZAHL_TEXT.text);
var c: Number = Number(player_3_content_mc.GESAMTPUNKTZAHL_TEXT.text);
var d: Number = Number(player_4_content_mc.GESAMTPUNKTZAHL_TEXT.text);

    if (a < d && c && b)
    player_1_content_mc.LEADER01_txt.text = "LEAD"

else

    player_1_content_mc.LEADER01_txt.text = ""

    if (b < d && c && a)
    player_2_content_mc.LEADER01_txt.text = "LEAD"

else

    player_2_content_mc.LEADER01_txt.text = ""

}
```

Can anyone help me understand why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an implementation that works with an arbitrary number of players. First you have to add all player movie clips to a list, then you can evaluate the player(s) with minimum number of points:

```
function showLeader(evt: KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    // create a list of all leaderboard movies.
    var movies : Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();

    movies.push(player_1_content_mc);
    movies.push(player_2_content_mc);
    movies.push(player_3_content_mc);
    movies.push(player_4_content_mc);

    // get minimum number of points
    var minNumber : Number = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    for each (var movie : MovieClip in movies)
    {
        var points : Number = Number(movie.GESAMTPUNKTZAHL_TEXT.text);

        if (points < minNumber) 
        {
            minNumber = points;
        }
    }

    // mark all players which have the minimum number of points
    // note: there can be more than one player with minimum number of points.
    for each (var movie : MovieClip in movies)
    {
        var points : Number = Number(movie.GESAMTPUNKTZAHL_TEXT.text);

        if (points == minNumber) 
        {
            // set text that this player is leader
            movie.LEADER01_txt.text = "LEAD";
        }
        else 
        {
            // clear textbox if player was previously lead
            movie.LEADER01_txt.text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I bow to this excellent solution! Thanks a lot MARIO, you did my day:)

Comment: Your welcome. Please upvote or mark it as accepted if my answer answered your question. This is how Stack Overflow tries to help others to quickly find useful answers. [Learn more...](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, I believe, has to do with the logical but inoperable shortcut that you took when comparing the players' scores

```
if (a < d && c && b)
```

The conventional way to do this is as such:

```
if (a < d && a < c && a < b)
```

And it's as simple as that!

But, if you end up adding more than 4 players, this method becomes tiring to type out. I would suggest adding all of the players to an array and looping through it to test players' scores.

Comment: Thanks to here! The problem is, if I choose just 3 players its still not working. Flash apperently needs four values in this case.

Comment: Ok, judging by your code, I'm assuming that it is good to have a low score (like in golf). In this case, the default score of a player that doesn't enter anything in is 0, thus making this ghost player win all the time. Let's just test to see if the score equals 0: `if (a < d && a < c && a < b && a != 0)`